# turtlesim initialises at x=[inf], y=[inf], theta=[0.000000]

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, turtlesim, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I execute

> ~$ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node

an empty blue "TurtleSim" simulation window pops up and the following messages are issued:

```
$ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
[ INFO] [1335558676.993640551]: Starting turtlesim with node name /turtlesim
[ INFO] [1335558677.369623672]: Spawning turtle [turtle1] at x=[inf], y=[inf], theta=[0.000000]
```

**Question 1 (of 2):** Why is turtle1 spawned at a location beyond the end of the universe, instead of at its origin [0,0] ?

I executed

> ~$ rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key

to see if the [x,y] coordinates would change when the up/down arrow keys were pressed, but unfortunately this is not the case. The [theta] value however -does- respond when the left/right arrow keys are pressed.

Output of the */turtle1/command_velocity* topic:

```
$ rostopic echo /turtle1/command_velocity
linear: 2.0
angular: 0.0
---
linear: -2.0
angular: 0.0
---
linear: 0.0
angular: 2.0
---
...
```

Output of the */turtle1/pose* topic:

```
...
---
x: inf
y: nan
theta: -3.06081461906
linear_velocity: 0.0
angular_velocity: 2.0
---
x: inf
y: nan
theta: -3.02881479263
linear_velocity: 0.0
angular_velocity: 2.0
---
x: inf
y: nan
theta: -2.99681472778
linear_velocity: 0.0
angular_velocity: 2.0
---
...
```

**Question 2 (of 2):** Is there perhaps a way to hard-set the [x,y] location ? E.g. something in the line of a command like "set turtle_pos=[0,0]" ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33041/turtlesim-initialises-at-x=%5Binf%5D,-y=%5Binf%5D,-theta=%5B0.000000%5D/) by [Need More Input](https://answers.ros.org/users/2260/need-more-input/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hard setting anything will not work in this case, because turtlesim has no clue how large a meter is supposed to be (it is initialized by the size of a turtle in the images directory).  To get turtlesim working without updating your ROS, you can copy the image files into /opt/ros/fuerte/share/turtlesim/images from the source download.

---

Originally posted by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) with karma: 218 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A ticket for this problem has been filed here:
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3942

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2